# Trying to move the footer to the bottom

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #23395b;
}

footer{
    background-color: #012a36;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -300px;
    margin-top: -200px; 
    height: 80px;
    clear:both;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
       }

footer ul{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2%;
    
}

footer li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 2%;
}

footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

footer a:hover{
    color: #00cecb;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">

    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HELP</a></li>
    </ul>      
       
</footer>
```

Trying to move the FOOTER to the bottom of the page. I have add absolute to the position but the body/html has increased when I change the bottom measurement. I have add div id = wrap but its look still same which leave lots of amount of space after the footer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ryan Fait's [Stick Footer](http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px;
    /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

footer,
.push {
    height: 80px;
    /* '.push' must be the same height as 'footer' */
}
```

**Note:** You'll have to remove the top and bottom padding on the footer element

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nbmh7p9/)

Comment: Did you remove the extra style rules like `position:absolute` and `margin-top:-200px`? In order for it to work you'll have to replace all the CSS you posted with the CSS in my fiddle.

Comment: I removed position and margin and replaced it all but looks the same.

Comment: Don't know what to tell you without seeing the code. You've either got an html structuring issue or CSS rules that are overriding the sticky footer rules.

Comment: i will give you the link sorry it's too large to post it you can see the view source. www.codeinventor.in

Comment: Add !important to * {margin: 0}

Comment: I add it everything changes including form, menu

Comment: Yeah a drawback is that other margins will be overridden. Your best bet with this solution is to assign them as !important one by one and make sure its not throwing off your footer.

Comment: I found the error of margin-bottom in paragraph. i removed and it works. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: No problem. Did my answer work? If so, don't forget to click the checkmark to accept it. If not, then don't.

Comment: Your answer works. Sorry I forgot to checkmark. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Make position: relative for body and bottom: 0 for footer. Also remove margin-top from footer.